# How to calculate n-per-time of of O(n log n)?

Tags: time-complexity

In a book by Aho, Hopcroft, and Ullman, an algorithm A1 has time complexity O(nlogn). The maximum problem size is 'n'.Assuming one unit of time is equal to one millisecond it was given that the Maximum Problem Size that can be solved during one second is 140, similarly in one minute it is 4,893 and for  one hour it is    2.0 × 10^5. Can any one explain how did they get this result?

Comment: I believe the book is proposing solving `t = n lg n` (that is using the bounding function directly and *ignoring* any C), where `t` is "time in milliseconds" - if so, see ["how to calculate n log n = c"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847327/how-to-calculate-n-log-n-c). Alternatively, graph the function and inspect the relevant X (n) values for the relevant Y (f(n) = O(n lg n)) values.

Answer (score 0):

```
140 * log 140 ~= 998ms ~ 1s
4,893 * log 4,893 ~= 59,971ms ~ 1min
```